# Derivative of matrix-valued function

Tags: calculus, matrices, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, matrix-calculus

Let $X=ZZ^\top$ where $Z$ is a full row rank $m\times n$ matrix and let $Y$ be a nonsingular $n\times n$ matrix. Consider the matrix-valued function
$$
f(X) = ZYZ^\top.
$$

> **My question:** Does there exists a closed form expression for the differential $\mathrm{d}f(X)$?

**Remark.** I believe that my question can be reduced to finding a closed form expression of the differential $\mathrm{d}Z$ w.r.t. $X$, but I don't know if this is actually possible.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as stated. What does $Z^\bot$ mean? $f$ is not a function of $X$.

Comment: @copper.hat I believe they're using the upside-down version of $\perp$; this would be the transpose.

Comment: @Clarinetist: You are correct, I meant $\top$.

Comment: Your function doesn't seem to be well defined since in general $X$ can be written using different matrices $Z$.

Comment: @copper.hat: $\top$ is standard notation for transposition. Since $Z$ is a "factor" of $X$, $f$ is a function of $X$ as well.

Comment: @JohnB: It is true that $X$ can be written using different $Z$, but I do not see how this would imply that the differential of $f$ is not well-defined.

Comment: Well, since your function is not well defined, it is hard that its differential is...

Comment: @JohnB: According to the answer below the differential is well-defined though.

Answer (score 4):

You could use vectorization to attack the problem.

First
$$\eqalign{
 X &= ZZ^T \cr
dX &= I\,dZ\,Z^T + Z\,dZ^T\,I \cr
dx &= \big((Z\otimes I) + (I\otimes Z)K\big)\,dz = A\,dz\cr
}$$ where $K$ is the kronecker commutation matrix such that
$${\rm vec}(Z^T) = K\,{\rm vec}(Z)$$

Next
$$\eqalign{
 F &= ZYZ^T \cr
dF &= I\,dZ\,YZ^T + ZY\,dZ^T\,I \cr
df &= \big((ZY^T\otimes I) + (I\otimes ZY)K\big)\,dz = B\,dz \cr
}$$
Then *assuming* that $A^{-1}$ exists
$$\eqalign{
df &= BA^{-1}\,dx \cr
dF &= {\rm mat}(df) = {\rm mat}(BA^{-1}\,dx) \cr
}$$ where mat() is the inverse of the vec() operator.

Comment: Your approach seems sound, but is it possible to avoid vectorization?

Comment: If $Z$ is rectangular, then $A$ is as well. In which case $A^{-1}$ **does not** exist. So this solution only works for $(m=n)$; or whenever $(A^+A=I)$.

Comment: But since the problem statement specifies _full row rank_, we know that $(A^+A \ne I)$. If it had specified _full column rank_, then this solution would work if $A^{-1}$ were replaced by the pseudoinverse.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the function is well defined , the simplest approach is to compute as follows:
$$
df(X)(WW^\top)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac1h((Z+hW)Y(Z+hW)^\top-ZYZ^\top)=ZYW^\top+WYZ^\top.
$$
The linear map $df(X)$ is being applyed to a vector $WW^\top$. Now you can use coordinates to write the derivative as a matrix.